# custom class converting errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

ive got a custom class for weapon stats,
then i have a weapon manager class that contains list of weapons with all theirs stats(unrealistic stats just plunked in just to get it running quickly for testing)

heres my weapon data class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WeaponData {

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public float Power {get; set;}
    public float Range {get; set;}
    public float Accuracy {get; set;}
    public float Mobility { get; set;}
    public int MaxAmmo{get; set;}
    public int CurrentAmmo{get;set;}
    public string Model {get; set;}

    //

    public WeaponData(){
        Name = "";
        Range = 0f;
        Power = 0f;
        Accuracy = 0f;
        Mobility = 0f;
        MaxAmmo = 0;
        CurrentAmmo = 0;
        Model = "";
    }

}
```

and heres my weapon manager class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WeaponMgr : WeaponData{

    public static WeaponMgr WM;

    public WeaponData Weapon;

    public WeaponMgr(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
    }

    //PRIMARY
    public WeaponData M4(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "M4 Carbine";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.5f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.5f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Model = "Aslt_M4Carbine";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;
    }
    public WeaponData M16(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "M16";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.5f;
        Weapon.Model = "Aslt_M16";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Ak47(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Ak 47";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.5f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.5f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Model = "Aslt_Ak47";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }

    //SMG

    public WeaponData MP5(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "MP5";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.7f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Model = "Smg_MP5";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData P90(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "P90";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.8f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Model = "Smg_P90";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Ak74(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "AK 74";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.2f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Model = "Smg_AK74";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Scorpion(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Scorpion";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.2f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.8f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.2f;
        Weapon.Model = "Smg_Scorpion";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }

    //Sniper
    public WeaponData BarretRifle(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = ".50 Caliber Barret Rifle";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.9f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Power = 1.0f;
        Weapon.Range = 1.0f;
        Weapon.Model = "Snp_BarretRifle";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Intervention(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Intervention";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 1.0f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Power = 1.0f;
        Weapon.Range = 1.0f;
        Weapon.Model = "Snp_Intervention";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData RemingtonRifle(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Remington 700";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.8f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.2f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.7f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.9f;
        Weapon.Model = "Snp_RemingtonRifle";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }

    //Shot Gun
    public WeaponData DoubleBarrel(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Double Barrel Shotgun";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.1f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.9f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.2f;
        Weapon.Model = "Shg_DoulbeBarrel";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData TwelveGauge(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "12. Gauge";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.2f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.8f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.1f;
        Weapon.Model = "Shg_12Gauge";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }


    //Pistol
    public WeaponData NineMM(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "9mm";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.5f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.9f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Model = "Pst_9mm";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Glock(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Glock";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.8f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Model = "Pst_Glock";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData DesertEagle(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "DesertEagle";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.7f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.7f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.5f;
        Weapon.Model = "Pst_DesertEagle";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Magnum(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Magnum Revolver";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.8f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.4f;
        Weapon.Model = "Pst_Magnum";
        Weapon.MaxAmmo = 20;
        Weapon.CurrentAmmo =20;
        return Weapon;

    }


    //SECONDARY


    //MELEE
    public WeaponData Fist(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Fist";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 1.0f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 1.0f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.1f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.02f;
        Weapon.Model = "Mle_Fist";
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Knife(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Knife";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.9f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.9f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.3f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.05f;
        Weapon.Model = "Mle_Knife";
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Hatchet(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Hatchet";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.7f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.5f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.05f;
        Weapon.Model = "Mle_Hatchet";
        return Weapon;

    }
    public WeaponData Katana(){
        Weapon = new WeaponData();
        Weapon.Name = "Katana";
        Weapon.Accuracy = 0.6f;
        Weapon.Mobility = 0.7f;
        Weapon.Power = 0.7f;
        Weapon.Range = 0.1f;
        Weapon.Model = "Mle_Katana";
        return Weapon;

    }
}
```

now when i try setting my player primary weapon variable which is  declared 
public WeaponData PrimaryWeapon;

and later try setting to equal to say... the M4
Player.PrimaryWeapon = new WeaponManager().M4;

it doesnt work i get errors
Cannot convert  method group "M4 to non-delgate type WeaponData.

What am i doing wrong here...?

im still rather new to C#
and self taught with few and very minimal examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730302/cannot-convert-method-group-tolist-to-non-delegate-type)

Answer (score 3):

A method name by itself is a "method group". It represents the group of overloads with that name. It can be used for delegate inference, but if you want to *call* the method, you have to add parentheses, even if there are not any arguments to pass.

Try:

```
Player.PrimaryWeapon = new WeaponManager().M4();
```

See the other answer for the explanation of the error you'll still have to deal with once you fix the method invocation (noting that the issue exists in all of the methods, not just `M4()`).

Answer (score 2):

You did not name the structure. So no variable is made.

```
public WeaponData M4(){
    Weapon m4 = new WeaponData();
    m4.Name = "M4 Carbine";
    m4.Accuracy = 0.6f;
    m4.Mobility = 0.5f;
    m4.Power = 0.5f;
    m4.Range = 0.6f;
    m4.Model = "Aslt_M4Carbine";
    m4.MaxAmmo = 20;
    m4.CurrentAmmo =20;
    return m4;
}
```