# Count the Number of elements in a string Array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am reading in data from a file into a list.  Once I have the data read in, I would like to split every string, and display the length of the split string. I have tried string.Length and string.Count, but nothing works.  How can I find the number of elements in my split string?

Here is the section of relevant code:

```
string fileread = openFileDialog1.Filename; //Opens file from computer
lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileread);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] Data_array = line.Split(',');
    List<string> Data_list = new List<string>();
    Data_list.Add(line);
    lbl_datacolumns.Text = Data_array.Count;//should show number of elements in Data_array
}
```

The error is: "Cannot Convert method group 'Count; to non-delegate type 'string'

Comment: What part of this doesn't work? If you want the cumulative count, then you'll have to sum the individual lengths.

Comment: @DStanley That's alright, I only need the last one, all lines should be equal length.  The problem is: "Cannot Convert method group 'Count; to non-delegate type 'string'"

Comment: Try to search. `Count()` is  a (extension) method, so you need to add parentheses to make it a method call. See [Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730302/cannot-convert-method-group-tolist-to-non-delegate-type). Then you get an `int` that you want to assign to a `string`. For that see [Convert int to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081916/convert-int-to-string) or just put the compiler error you get in your favorite web search engine.

Comment: @CodeCaster Do I need to convert Data_array into an int before applying Count()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Length` property:

```
lbl_datacolumns.Text = Data_array.Length.ToString();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5m6Wk8

Comment: That still gives me the error: Cannot convert Method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'.....

Comment: @manateejoe then you again think you can omit the parentheses from a method call. You can't, this isn't Visual Basic.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have added the parentheses and I am still getting the error  EDIT: Never mind, restarting the program helped.  Thanks!