# c# in Visual Studio delegate and exception error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have an exception error with the "Files" and a delegate error with " byte[] B = MS.ToArray;"

First error tells me this:
*Method name expected*

The second error tells me this:
*Cannot convert method group to non-delegate type 'byte[]'. Did you intend to invoke the method?*

I am not 100% Why I am getting these errors with this.

If more code is needed from the project let me know.

My question is not a dupe as I also have a second error with Files that needs addressing.

Thanks in advance.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label2.Text = ".Png to animated .Gif started.";
        label2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.Refresh();
        string GifFolder = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Gif";
        string GifFile = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Gif\\FinalGif\\GIF" + Convert.ToString(Counter) + ".Gif";
        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(GifFolder, "*.Png");
        MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryReader BR = new BinaryReader(MS);
        BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(GifFile, FileMode.Create));
        Image.FromFile(Files(0)).Save(MS, ImageFormat.Gif);
        byte[] B = MS.ToArray;
        B(10) = B(10) & 0x78;
        BW.Write(B, 0, 13);
        BW.Write(GifAnimation);
        WriteGifImg(B, BW);
        for (int I = 1; I <= Files.Length - 1; I++)
        {
            MS.SetLength(0);
            Image.FromFile(Files(I)).Save(MS, ImageFormat.Gif);
            B = MS.ToArray;
            WriteGifImg(B, BW);
        }
        BW.Write(B(B.Length - 1));
        BW.Close();
        MS.Dispose();
        label2.Text = ".Png to animated .Gif complete.";
        label2.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        if (File.Exists("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Gif\\\\FinalGif\\GIF.Gif"))
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Gif\\GIF.Gif");
        }
        else {
            pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730302/cannot-convert-method-group-tolist-to-non-delegate-type)

Comment: Agree, @EugenePodskal.

Comment: Now that I see that question it is a half dupe a guess as I also have another problem that I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its looks you have used to program in basic and other languages like that.
in C the parenthesis after method name (when invoking) is required even there is no argument. and the array indexes should be between brackets [] (your another mistake)
so you should write:
    File.Open(files[i]);

for example, where files is an array or list or collection ...

Comment: Cheers, I don't know why I didn't see this they are such simple mistakes.